# Typescript is converting files "above" tsconfig folder

Tags: typescript

Crazy problem. Have not touched tsconfig file in a long time and suddenly I have this problem

Folder structure:

- backend
- frontend

  - tsconfig.json

My tsconfig.json

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

Positioned in `frontend`. I run `tsc`. Now I get errors from the `backend` folder.

It only happens in production. Not in development node.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also include in your post the error that you get?

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?